# bindValue in INSERT wont work

Tags: php, mysql

My code -

```
$con = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=air','root','123456');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $fields = implode(", ", $fields);
    echo $fields;
    $values = implode("','", $values);
    echo $values;

    // have to make this prevent sql injection //
    // it wont work if i added bindValue why? //
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(ID, $fields) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindValue(1,'',PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(2,$values,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    //if I remove `bindValue` and replace this it will insert //
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(ID, $fields) VALUES ('', $values)");
```

why after I add `bindValue` my insert wont work anymore , but when I use normal `sql` , it will work , what wrong with my `bindValue` and the VALUES (?,?) ,can anyone help me take a look ??

Comment: Does "not work" lead to an error message you might wanna reveal? What do $fields and $values contain? Why don't you just pass them through `->execute([...])`?

Comment: since you're inserting `$values` as array of string, you should build the question mark placeholders dynamically also

Comment: you can't bind fields in bulk. You have to bind them individually. Also, to bind null for your id field, use `bindValue(2,NULL,PDO::PARAM_NULL);`

Comment: so is better just pass them through execute ~~ i understand i will give it a try

Comment: wont work , i tryed this and remove the bindvalue

Comment: $stmt->execute(array('',$values)); i replace the '' to null also , didt work

Answer (score 0):

I am late here, but a Simple handy function that could used anyone searching for the answer to achieve binding and inserting to any table and fields. Haven't included `PDO::PARAM_STR` as its default ant i see that your fields are all `string` values. Hope this helps :)

```
//get array containing fields and its values to be added $fv_array
$fv_array=array(
"field_one_name"=>$field_one_value,
"field_two_name"=>$field_two_value,
"field_three_name"=>$field_three_value
);

$con=new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=air','root','123456');
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$fv="";
 //create string like :field_one_name,:field_two_name,:field_three_name,
foreach($fv_array as $field=>$value {$fv.=":".$field.",";}
//rtrim removes trailing comma
$statement=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$table." (".implode(",",array_keys($fv_array)).") VALUES (".rtrim($fv, ",").")");
//bind values
foreach($fv_array as $field=>$value){$statement->bindValue(':'.$field,$value);}
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what $fields and $values are but i assume there is nothing wrong with these. You are trying to pass a bindValue of string into an id field. Can you try and change it to PDO::PARAM_INT ?